# How to know if a Knowledge Article Version is deleted?

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, articles

I've deleted a Knowledge Article Type, and when I look in the KnowledgeArticleVersion object, I see all the versions of that type, with IsDeleted = false, and their ArticleType now seems to be something generic ("ka0", "ka4").
I'm trying to understand if there's a way to know which versions belong to articles of deleted Article Types via Apex code or a SOQL query (there's no indication on the version nor KnowledgeArticle).
Based on Salesforce documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_types_delete.htm&language=en&type=0), Article Types aren't deleted/don't go to the recycle bin and instead go to some other storage (which I don't seem to have access to).

1 solution would be to retrieve all article versions and for each try and sample the existence of that ArticleType as an object by querying/schema, and then filtering those failing - this isn't very performance friendly and quite an ugly solution.

Is there some other way I would be able to achieve this?

Comment: The KnowledgeArticleVersion Object has a field ArticleType. Try to leverage that.

Comment: Yes, one idea was, as suggested, sample if that exists.. but that means an extra query/api call/schema access per each type - I was hoping for something less brute.

Comment: I am affraid there is no other "soft" way to do this. Sooner or later, you have to filter by the article type. Consider having a "black list"  with the deleted articles, and filter them out during the query. The drawback of going for this approach is obvious as you have to consistently keep track manually to the deleted article types.

Comment: That's what I fear too.
But I was hoping to do something like a join query - find some table that contains all deleted article types and join it against the versions.
Just like there's an isDeleted field on regular objects.